# Aggregating nmon reports - AIX

Tags: performance-monitor, aix

Is there a tool to aggregate nmon reports of the same server over a period of days/hours and get a summary of (min,max,avg) of CPU memory etc.

Currently we have each server generating nmon data every 8hrs.

We also have cfg2web to obtain reports - is there a way to perform aggregate reporting using utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nmon2rrd` and/or `nmon2web`.

Info on the [nmon wiki](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/WikiPtype/nmon).

You can also use nmonmerge (same page), and then graph in the regular Excel tool ([nmon analyzer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/Wikiptype/nmonanalyser)).